# How to combine force www and nicer URLs?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In the root directory I am forcing `www.` via `.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.org$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.org/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

So `example.org` becomes `www.example.org`.

In a sub directory `/products` I have another `.htaccess` with a rewrite for the usage of nicer URLs with slashes instead of search queries

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /products/
    rewriteRule     ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$  $1/                             [NC,R=301,L]
    RewriteRule     ^([a-z0-9-]+)/([0-9-]+)/$       products.php?name=$1&version=$2     [NC]
    RewriteRule     ^([a-z0-9-]+)/$                 products.php?name=$1                [NC]
</IfModule>
```

For some reason if I enter `example.org/products/` no `www.` is enforced. Is the sub directory rule somehow interfering with that rule? How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because apache doesnt read your root htaccess. Apache reads your subfolder htacess for subfolder requests. To force www for /products/ you need to put the following rule in your /products/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,L,R]
```

Comment: Seems right to me. In the meanwhile I fixed it with a similar approach by deleting the sub directory `.htaccess` file and adding the code accordingly changed to the root. But probably changing the sub directory `.htaccess` file is more efficient.